# Html5 application with access to server database

Tags: database, html, web-services, web-applications, websocket

I am developing a cross platform html5 application and all is going well but I keep hitting a brick wall on how to make the application post and retrieve data from a database on a server.

I have tried using a php handler on the server but whenever I send data to it, the application closes and goes to the browser.

How can I allow the forms in my html5 application to store and edit information in tables hosted on a remote server?

Thank you.

-edit-
my code inside the html5 application:

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

my code on the server:

```
    <html>
    <body>

    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Yes, I am using a wrapper to allow the html5 application to run on multiple platforms. I just don't want to exit the wrapper and go into the browser whenever i send data from the form in the application to the php handler on the server.

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Comment: This is not an html5 question.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp . Did you check previous steps? Do you have a running php+apache configuration?

Comment: The "the application closes and goes to the browser" part suggests he's using some kind of mobile wrapper, the question simply seems to be how that specific wrapper handles non local urls.